# How to add .delay to .click on .each iteration (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, delayed-execution

So, I want to put delay on this JavaScript code.

```
$(function(){ 
     $('.clickThis').each(function(){ 
         $(this).click();
     }); 
});
```

I tried this

```
$(function(){ 
     $('.clickThis').each(function(){
         $(this).click().delay(5000); 
     }); 
});
```

above script doesnt work .

Is there any alternative?

I've tried Google it but I still couldn't figure it out, because I have little knowledge in JavaScript.

Comment: Docs are your friends. `The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.` http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Answer (score 9):

This will do it:

```
$(function(){ 
    $('.clickThis').each(function(i, that){ 
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(that).click();
        }, 5000*i );
    }); 
});
```

Comment: except that if there are more than one .clickthis, the second one won't wait for the first one to be triggered to start waiting 5sec before being triggered

Comment: @mikakun there's no need to wait - this code will attempt to trigger each click 5 seconds apart, not 5 seconds from "completion" of the previous click.  Your own code does the same

Comment: @Ainitak yeah ok didn't see the `*i` at first look; why not (would still use my solution though seems better semantic than have all those timeout going on at the same time)

Comment: @mikakun don't take this the wrong way, but I wouldn't use your code.  It's far less clear than this version.  It's messy too.

Comment: @Alnitak my code makes only one access to the dom whatever the number of item; here you have one access at every item + the initial $(".clickthis') + nothing is cached

Comment: @mikakun no, this version does exactly the same DOM access as yours.  If there is a valid criticism of this solution it's that it schedules `n` timers all in one go, but using `setInterval` isn't the right way to fix that - it would be to start the next timer each time through the loop.  Roger's answer links to that, but there's no up votes just for linking to someone else's blog.

Comment: wrong `$(that)` is extra job compare to `eq(i)` or `[i]` on a cached object; & please expand on why using setInterval is bad compare to looping timeout... i'm curious

Comment: @mikakun both `$(that)` and `.eq(i)` create a new jQuery object and have the same cost, but neither will require any DOM access. `[i]` is just wrong, because that's the DOM element, not a jQuery object.  `setInterval` is potentially dangerous because it can result in multiple events all firing immediately after the other, whereas calling `setTimeout` in each iteration guarantees that each iteration _cannot_ start until 5s after the last one finished.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a version using a recursive `setTimeout` loop.

```
$(function() {
    var click = $('.clickThis').toArray();

    (function next() {
        $(click.shift()).click();   // take (and click) the first entry
        if (click.length) {         // and if there's more, do it again (later)
            setTimeout(next, 5000);
        }
    })();
});
```

The advantage of this pattern over `setTimeout(..., 5000 * i)` or a `setInterval` call is that only a single timer event is ever queued at once.

In general, repeated calls to `setTimeout` are better than a single call to `setInterval` for a few reasons:

1. `setInterval` calls can queue up multiple events even if the browser isn't active, which then all fire as quickly as possibly when the browser becomes active again.  Calling `setTimeout` recursively guarantees that the minimum time interval between events is honoured.
2. With `setInterval` you have to remember the timer handle so you can clear it

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
$(function () {
    var items=$('.clickThis');
    var length=items.length;
    var i=0;
    var clickInterval=setInterval(function(){
        items.eq(i).click();
        i++;
        if(i==length)
            clearInterval(clickInterval);
    }, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write an asynchronous setTimeout loop, for more information http://www.erichynds.com/javascript/a-recursive-settimeout-pattern/

Answer (score 0):

```
var $clickthis=$(".clickthis");
var i= -1;
var delayed = setInterval(function(){
 if (++i < $clickthis.length) $clickthis.eq(i).trigger("click");
 else clearInterval(delayed);
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure but I think that setTimeout function should do the trick.
See here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout

Comment: Generally answers should only link out to third party resources to support the answer. You shouldn't use them as your actual answer. I know it is tempting as getting answers in fast enough is pretty hard on SO. (PS I didnt downvote).

Comment: I down voted.  Firstly, because of the reason mrtsherman gave.  Secondly, because you posted a link without actually knowing whether it would help.  Answers are supposed to be definitive, not "guesses".

Comment: Sorry, I thought this documentation was the best explanation. I will take time to give a better answer the next time.

Comment: Thank you for the link, the top answer is also using setTimeout. I wish your link would help me to figure out how the top answer's work .

Comment: @user2054689 the top answer works simply because `.each()` calls the supplied function with the index of the current element, so you end up with `n` timers each starting at `5000 * i`.

Answer (score -3):

Try

```
$(function(){ 
     $('.clickThis').each(function(_,i){ 
        var me=$(this);
        setTimeout(function(){me.click()},5000*i);
     ); 
});
```

Comment: this fires all the click events in one go, not 5s apart.

Comment: He didn't mention that he want them to fire one by one. If that's the case, he could just multiply the loop index by the interval.

Comment: he did say "in each iteration", and multiplying by the loop index is what the current top answer does (even though that answer actually has a bug in it).

Comment: Where did he say "in each iteration"? I can't see that in his question content. Maybe he styled it with `display:none` ? :)

Comment: Well deadlock, thanks for the answer. Sory, I forgot to mention what Alnitak said. I want the click event work one by one .

Comment: @deadlock it's in the question subject.